# Error in UITableview when pull down to refresh, all data repeating itself. Can any one help using Swift3 , Xcode8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8, uirefreshcontrol

I have data coming from database in my `UITableView`, when I try to pull down to make refresh all data in my tableview repeat itself and when I am trying to put a new data in database and making refresh nothing happens.

This is my code

```
 class MyTable: UITableViewController {

   var refresh = UIRefreshControl()
   @IBAction func SharaOn(_ sender: UIButton) {
   }
   var mydata = [TestTable]()
   let backendless = Backendless()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   refresh = UIRefreshControl()
   refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector (MyTable.pullDown), for: .valueChanged)

      tableView.addSubview(refresh)

      }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         loaddatawithquery()
   }


     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of  sections
    return 1
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
       return mydata.count
      }


     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell") as? MyTableCell{



        let ImgURL = URL(string : self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL!)
       let Desc = self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Desc!
        cell.MyText.text = Desc
        cell.mainImage.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)

        return cell

       }else{

        let cell = MyTableCell()
        let ImgURL = URL(string : self.mydata [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL)
         let Desc = self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Desc

        cell.mainImage.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)

        cell.MyText.text = Desc!

        return cell
        }


        }


         func updateLikes() {
            let LikeBu = TestTable()
             let updaterecord =       Backendless.sharedInstance().data.of(TestTable.ofClass())


              LikeBu.LikeNo = 1
              updaterecord?.save(LikeBu, response: { (result) in
                  print("udateed successfully \(result)")
                   }, error: { (Fault) in
                   print("EROrrrrrrrrrr")
               })


             }
         func loaddatawithquery(){


    _ = "ImgURL"
    _ = "Desc"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.queryOptions.pageSize=50

   // dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

       backendless.data.of(TestTable.ofClass()).find(dataQuery,response: {(result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in
         let data = result?.getCurrentPage()

    for obj in data! as! [TestTable] {

            self.mydata.append(obj)

        //print("&&&&&&&hhhjjjhhvkhkh \(obj.Desc!) &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")


        self.tableView.reloadData()


        }
        },
        error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "info", message:"يرجى الاتصال بالانترنيت", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in

                                         })

self.present(alert, animated: true){}


    })


}
@IBAction func likebutton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   // updateLikes()

}


func pullDown() {


    for  data in mydata   {

        self.mydata.append(data)
    }

    self.refresh.endRefreshing()

}





 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can understand, its because of this code here

```
for  data in mydata   {

    self.mydata.append(data)
}
```

Here actually you are iterating the data inside the tableview, and also adding the data already there, and also fetching new data, hence in the actual array `self.mydata`, there are 2 sets of similar objects.
I think a better approach would be if you can just append the new data after the query or you can empty the array and then load the whole data from your database.

Let me know.

Comment: I try to do it , but when I add a new data in my data base and pull down no thing happen .

Comment: The code you are using now will append new data and old data hence, there are 2 sets of old data so you are getting duplicate data in the array.

Comment: Do you men to delete the func of pulldown and use instead of it the func of loaddatawithquery ?  if mean that , I tried to do it but still the same error .

Comment: No, inside the func of pulldown, instead of appending, call the func loaddatawithquery with a bigger page size (bigger count of array, that you want to show after pulling)

Comment: Ok , I do it but still the same error all data repeat it self again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code like this:-

```
func pullDown() {

   var temp = [TestTable]()

    for  data in mydata   {
        temp.append(data)
    }
    mydata.removeAll()
    mydata = temp
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refresh.endRefreshing()

}
```

Comment: I do it but still the same error no thing happen when add new data and pull down.

Comment: I have edited my answer assuming that you have the new data in mydata object before calling pullDown.